# Rails validating with condition block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation

Rails AR. validate one field, with 4 validators & 2 condition block

```
validates :inn,
          presence: { if: -> { user.is_a?(Client) } },
          inn: { if: -> { user.is_a?(Client) } },
          uniqueness: { if: -> { user.is_a?(Client) } },
          absence: { if: -> { user.is_a?(Department) } }
```

Could I have some tips on refactoring this?

Comment: `inn` as an option of `validates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (obviously names can be shorter):

```
if_user_is_a = ->(klass) { { if: -> { user.is_a?(klass) } } }
validates :inn, presence: if_user_is_a[Client], ..., absence: if_user_is_a[Department]
```

or

```
if_user_is_a = ->(klass) { { if: -> { user.is_a?(klass) } } }
if_user_is_a_client = if_user_is_a[Client]
...
validates :inn, presence: if_user_is_a_client, ...
```

Comment: It seems better, but maybe is it something better than that?

Comment: It seems there isn't any better than that. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you split both conditions into 2 diffrent validations? I think it's cleaner and easier to read (ie more maintenable).

```
validates :inn, presence: true, uniqueness: true, if: :user_is_client #no idea about that `inn` option on your example
validates :inn, absence: true, if: :user_is_department

def user_is_client
  user.is_a?(Client)
end

def user_is_department
  user-is_a?(Department)
end
```

Personally, I prefer to be more verbose some times. Also, I think this way conditions are checked only once each, the other way each condition is checked for each validation since rails has to evaluate all blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a method instead of repeat yourself 4 times

Something like:

```
validates :inn,
          presence: { inn_meth { Client } },
          inn: { inn_meth { Client } },
          uniqueness: { inn_meth { Client} },
          absence: { inn_meth{ Department } }

def inn_meth
    if: -> { user.is_a?(yield) }
end
```